# How does explain() work in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Per [MongoDB Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/#plan-cache-flushes) '...For each query, the query planner searches the query plan cache for an entry that fits the query shape...', then later  '... 'Changed in version 2.6: explain() operations no longer read from or write to the query planner cache.' How does explain() work in the **current** MongoDB version if it does not involve searching the query planner cache?

Comment: Kind of broad. If you want to know about the different modes of retrieval then read about them in the documentation, under the ["explain"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/explain/) command. Everything in MongoDB is a "command", so if you are looking for the "meat" of how things work, then it is these you should be looking at.

Comment: The 'query optimizer' link in the 'explain' command link posits that '...For each query, the query planner searches the query plan cache for an entry that fits the query shape...', then at the end adds that 'Changed in version 2.6:  explain() operations no longer read from or write to the query planner cache', which confuses me: how does it work in versions later than 2.6?